# Using SVNAnt in eclipse Build Failed (Could not load definitions from resource)

Tags: eclipse, svn, ant

I want to use SVNAnt in eclipse.
But when I run my script, I have this message :

```
Buildfile: X:\XXX\bin\ant\axis_bujava.xml
  [typedef] Could not load definitions from resource org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml. It could not be found.
testSVNAnt:

BUILD FAILED
X:\XXX\bin\ant\axis_bujava.xml:11: Problem: failed to create task or type svn
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Here is the Ant build file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="testSVNAnt" basedir=".">

<path id="path.svnant">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnant.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />
    <target name="testSVNAnt">
        <svn username="username" password="pass">
            <checkout url="svn://svnurl" destPath="localpath" revision="HEAD"/>  
        </svn>
        <echo message= "Subversion repository url: ${repository.url}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

The JAR files are of course in basedir. I can't find similar problem nor any solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finaly work using SvnAnt 1.3.1.

The checkout work fine using this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="main" basedir=".">

    <path id="path.svnant">
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnant.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnClientAdapter.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnjavahl.jar" />

    </path>

    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />
    <target name="main">
        <svn>
            <checkout url="svn://xxx" destPath="X:/XXX" revision="HEAD" />
        </svn>
    </target>
</project>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
<taskdef />
```

instead of `<typedef/>`

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: This modification does not change anything for me.

Comment: @thomaf can you verify that org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml is in svnant.jar

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem.. replacing the value of "resource" from "org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" TO "svntask.properties" did it for me.

sample below: (svn_1.0.0; eclipse juno)

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
<classpath>
  <pathelement location="D:/.../ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
</classpath>
</taskdef>      
<path id="path.svnant">
    <pathelement location="D:/.../lib/svnant.jar" />
    <pathelement location="D:/.../lib/svnClientAdapter.jar" />
    <pathelement location="D:/.../lib/svnjavahl.jar" />

</path>

<typedef **resource="svntask.properties"** classpathref="path.svnant"/>

<target name="ifAvailable">
    <available classpathref="path.svnant" **resource="svntask.properties"** 
    property="temp"/>
        <echo message="SVNAnt is available = ${temp}"></echo>   
</target>
```

OUTPUT>>>>>

```
Buildfile: D:\...\build.xml
```

ifAvailable:
     [echo] SVNAnt is available = true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 306 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <taskdef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" />
```

with

```
 <taskdef resource="svntask.properties"/>
```

The svntask.properties are present in the svnant.jar